# Sound Intensity Measurements convert to Sound Power

Tags: acoustics

If you need to have Sound Power results and the location that the microphone needs to be to make the measurement(per the standard) is not accessible. There is a machine part in between the measurements surface and mic location. In addition the noise source is a tire rotating on a drum.

I was told to make the multiple measurement using SI and then convert to Pw.

1. How much will the reflective surface influence the SI measurement?
2. To calculate the point required for the mic position is ~ 1/2 the distance specified by the standard. Can you using the inverse square law to correct the value?
3. What is the best way to convert SI to Pw?
4. Does anyone have a better way to make this measurement without a lot of R&D studies to understnad the results?
5. How can I validate my results if this approach is used?
6. Can anyone share a public reference paper to help with this issue?
   Thanks Tony

Comment: For (3), SI = SP/Area; if you know SI at certain radii, $r$, then $A=4\pi r^2$ and you can get SP easily. Not sure about any of the others.